# How to use for loop in launch file in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How can implement for loop concept in gazebo to spawn multiple robot model?
For example:

```
<include file="$(find manycar)/launch/azcar.launch">
<arg name="robot_num" value="1"/>
<arg name="init_pose" value="-x 1 -y 1 -z 0 -Y 1.57 "/>
</include>
```

I want to iterate above code n times, variable being `robot_num`'s value.
How should I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12256/how-to-use-for-loop-in-launch-file-in-gazebo?/) by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-12-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Maybe you could use embedded ruby the same way it can be used for SDF.

See [this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/e024fe922c810f468e2a7ab277750354465478cd/cart_front_steer/model.rsdf?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#model.rsdf-79) SDF example where wheels are generated in a for loop for a cart.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) on 2021-01-07**:
Years passed, the link https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/e024fe922c810f468e2a7ab277750354465478cd/cart_front_steer/model.rsdf?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#model.rsdf-79 looks broken to me.